# Save Contents Of a TextBox To a File

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-mobile, file-io, windows-mobile-5.0

I'm developing an application that has a TextBox. I want to write its contents to a file, but how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this, the simplest being:

```
 using(var stream = File.CreateText(path))
 {
      stream.Write(text);
 }
```

Be sure to look at the MSDN page for [`File.CreateText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx) and [`StreamWriter.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce2kyyb4.aspx).

If you weren't targeting the .NET Compact Framework, as your tags suggest, you could do even simpler:

```
 File.WriteAllText(path, string);
```

Comment: Thanks for your example and the reading indications, principally because of the indications! Continue like this! ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("myfile.txt", textBox.Text);
```

If you're stuck on some brain-dead version of the BCL, then you can write that function yourself:

```
static void WriteAllText(string path, string txt) {
    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txt);
    using (var f = File.OpenWrite(path)) {
        f.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // replace string with your file path and name file.
  using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("line.txt"))
  {
    sw.WriteLine(MyTextBox.Text);
  }
}
```

Of course, add exception handling etc.

Comment: Duh! `using` *is* exception handling!

Comment: I meant some `try-catch` phrases to let the user know that a. the file cannot be created b. he has no permissions c. the text box is empty etc.

Answer (score 0):

For a richTextBox, you can add a "Save" button for this purpose. Also add a saveFileDialog control from Toolbox, then add following code in button's click event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult Result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();//Show the dialog to save the file.
    //Test result and determine whether the user selected a file name from the saveFileDialog.
   if ((Result == DialogResult.OK) && (saveFileDialog1.FileName.Length > 0))
   {
       //Save the contents of the richTextBox into the file.
       richTextBox1.SaveFile(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
   } 
}
```